# How to create an html link to another page from "<?=$objResult["id"];?>"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php/mysql application and need to make the output of one column, one row an html link to another html page.  Have not been able to find any relavant information.  The "" needs to be the link. Thanks for any help.

```
<table id="display" style="width:800px;">
<tr>
<th width="40">ID</th>
<th width="70">Last</th>
<th width="70">First</th>
<th width="10">Middle</th>
<th width="70">Birth</th>
<th width="70">Death</th>
<th width="170">Notes</th>
<th width="100">Cemetery</th>
</tr>
<?
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
?>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["id"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["last"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["first"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["middle"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["birth"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["death"];?></td>
<td><?=$objResult["notes"];?></td>
<td style='text-align:center;'><?=$objResult["cemetery"];?></td>
</tr>
<?
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: why don't you just wrap the $objResult around <a></a> tags?

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Funny how we never think of the easy way and look for the complicated way.  Have a good day.